# Getting duplicate key values from SQL Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

As you know SQL Server 2008+ gives us the courtesy of knowing what values are duplicate by saying

> The duplicate key value is (foo, bar)

in the `SqlException` message. Normally I get these values by using a regex and getting the data between the parentheses' to show it to end user.

I'm wondering; is there a more elegant way to get those values?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is an elegant way, I would handle it the way you do with RegEx.

Answer (score -3):

this is a **sample**... this get **value** of *specified field* , and **compare** with **textBox1** (here the user insert what they want)...

```
oleDbConnection1.open();
string query = "select * from database";
OleDbCommand comand = new OleDbCommand(query,oleDbConnection1);
OleDbDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
string value = reader.getValue(1).ToString();
reader.Close();
if(textBox1.Text == value)
{
MessageBox.Show("Data Dublicate","Error");
}
```